# Re-arrange and remove elements inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a repeating container with a few span elements. I would like to remove two, and re-arrange one of the elements as the example below. I started with something like this:

```
$('span.class5').insertBefore('span.class0');
```

This added each span.class5 found on page inside each repeating container, so that didn't work.. How do I do this best with jQuery?

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">

 <div class="group">
    <span class="class0"></span>
    <span class="class1"></span>
    <span class="class2"></span>
    <span class="class3"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4"></span>
    <span class="class5"></span>
    <span class="class6"></span>
    <span class="class7"></span>
    <span class="class8"></span>
 </div>

</div>
```

Rearrange to:

```
 <div class="container">

 <div class="group">
    <span class="class0"></span>
    <span class="class5"></span>
    <span class="class1"></span>
    <span class="class2"></span> = remove
    <span class="class3"></span> = remove
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4"></span>
    <span class="class6"></span>
    <span class="class7"></span>
    <span class="class8"></span>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `= remove`? Do they just need to get removed, or is = remove part of your HTML?

Comment: I need to remove them - thats the easier part though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution possible :
*( with jQuery)*

```js
// I would like to remove two
$('.class2 , .class3' , '.group').remove();

//This added each span.class5 found on page inside each repeating container
$('span.class5').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this);
  var $father = $el.parents('.container');
  
  //         if you don't want to use a class for the container
  //         decomment line under
  //var $father = $el.parent().parent();
  
  
  $el.insertAfter($father.find('.class0'))
});
```

```css
span{
  border : solid 1px #EEE;
  display : inline-block;
  padding : 3px;
  margin : 3px;
  }

.container{
  border : solid 1px #CCC;
  padding 3px;
  margin : 3px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - my page has 10  repeating containers and it adds the amount of the class5 element on the page to each container.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parent > child selector to restrict operations to a specific container:

```js
function rearrange(num) {
  $('.container' + num + ' > .group > .class2').remove();
  $('.container' + num + ' > .group > .class3').remove();
  $('.container' + num + ' > .group > .class5').insertBefore($('.container' + num + ' > .group > .class0'));
}
```

```css
.group {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 4px
}
.group span {
  margin: 3px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
  <button onclick="rearrange(1)">Rearrange</button>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class0">0</span>
    <span class="class1">1</span>
    <span class="class2">2</span>
    <span class="class3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="class4">4</span>
    <span class="class5">5</span>
    <span class="class6">6</span>
    <span class="class7">7</span>
    <span class="class8">8</span>
  </div>
  <button onclick="rearrange(2)">Rearrange</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the container is repeating with the same class - i cant change it to group1, group2 etc.

Comment: Ok, so how will you identify wich container is the one to use? By the order of the containers?

Comment: I want this to happen to all the containers, they are all the same. But I have 10 containers like this - this code gives me 10 class5 elements inside each container. I want the move to be restricted to only happen inside its parent container.